# Will the third heaven also be made new?

Tags: revelation, heaven

I am currently studying the third heaven, which is described as Paradise (2 Cor 12:1-4) and seems to contain the throne room of God, described elsewhere (eg. Rev 4:1-11). The first heaven appears to describe the earthly atmosphere - where birds fly, etc. (Gen 6:7).

When all things are made new, as described in Revelation 21:1 - “a new heaven, and a new earth” will replace their old counterparts.

My question is, will the new creation include a new third heaven?

To provide more context to my question… My studies have led me to understand that Paradise/Heaven is not an uncontaminated place. Ezekiel 28 describes Lucifer in Paradise, in the presence of God. Verse 15 tells us that one day, iniquity was found within him - sin entered heaven. It therefore seems reasonable that heaven would be made new.

Comment: "Ezekiel 28 describes Lucifer in Paradise, in the presence of God." Err what? "Verse 15 tells us that one day, iniquity was found within him - sin entered heaven." Err what? Perhaps you might want to check that. The word 'lucifer' (an archaic name for the planet venus) occurs once in the bible in a few mainly older translations, in Isaiah 14:12 in a prophecy against the king of Babylon. It does not appear in Ezekiel 28, prophetic against the kings of Tyre and Sidon. There is nothing in verse 15 to do with heaven. Please open a bible before you ask questions.